# Dependency Injection in iOS

Tags: ios5, dependency-injection

Basically, I am trying to write the Test cases using XCTest Framework available in the iOS. So I came across this DI and was exploring it on Google where I came across [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782398/recommended-ioc-framework-for-ios) and [Objection](http://objection-framework.org). But I am unable to understand as how to integrate this into the project. Could anybody guide me as how can achieve this?

Is it necessary to use DI or is there any work around on it?

May be is there any other available DI Framework available for iOS we can use as I am not able to understand how to implement the Objection Framework?

Comment: Check this [enter link description here][1], You can find your answer in detail 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8782398/recommended-ioc-framework-for-ios

Comment: I have already gone through this link, but did not find it useful in terms of implementation.I did not find any documentation of it.Could you let me know how to use it in any Xcode project?

Comment: This link shows an example with xcode project. http://objection-framework.org/

Comment: i am unable to run the code.It is saying `ipo: can't open input file: /Users/portia/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Objection-freoyqhgfcvkmagdhjnbgkguekvv/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libObjection-StaticLib.a (No such file or directory)
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
` I added the libObjection-Static.a file but still getting the same error. I also added the **HeaderSearchPath** to it but still not able to run the code.